# parse a really simple markup grammar with a shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have to parse a file, kind of a config file, that is adopting a really simple grammar : there are 2 kind of multiline blocks and inline markup tags .

the block of type 1 is marked by an *open_tag* and a *closing_tag* plus the name of the block, example

```
START_BLOCK_1 name
   < content >
END_BLOCK_1
```

blocks of type 1 only contain blocks of type 2, they are basically used to switch on or off blocks of this configuration file .

the block of type 2 is marked by a tag at the start of a new line ( plus the name ) and there is non closing tag, the closing is implicitly made when a new block starts or when the file ends, the block itself is allowed to contain empty lines .

```
START_BLOCK_2 name_1
    < content >
    < content >
    < content >

START_BLOCK_2 name_2

    < content >

    < content >
    < content >

START_BLOCK_2 name_3
    < content >
    < content >
```

the final kind of token is just an inline tag, a special word that is present at the start of the line and I just to get what is the value marked by that tag

```
START_BLOCK_2 name_1

    tag_1 red

    tag_2 Jon

START_BLOCK_2 name_2
    tag_1 blue
    tag_2 Phil
```

A good final example could be

```
START_BLOCK_2 name_1
    < content >

START_BLOCK_2 name_2

    < content >

START_BLOCK_1 name_1
    START_BLOCK_2 name_3
        < content >

    START_BLOCK_2 name_4

        < content >

END_BLOCK_1

START_BLOCK_2 name_5
    < content >
```

Considering the names of blocks of type 2 I need to know the values associated to each tag ( if they contain tags that are set ) and if they are part of type 1 blocks and in this case the name attribute of the type 1 block that contains them .

The result could be stored in a file or printed out, as long as I can parse this I can always re-read the output later in a formatted way .

It's relatively simple to parse this file but I have never done such thing with just a GNU/linux shell and I would like to know if this is possible and the names of the tools made for this .

EDIT

input

```
START_BLOCK_2 opt1
color red

START_BLOCK_1 opt2
    START_BLOCK_2 opt3
        name Jon

    START_BLOCK_2 opt4

        color blu

END_BLOCK_1
```

expected output

```
opt1 red

opt3 opt2
opt3 Jon

opt4 opt2
opt4 blu
```

Comment: While you could probably make something work with, say, `awk`, in general parsing problems do better with real parsers, and so I'd usually write one in another language like python or perl

Comment: @EricRenouf the only reason why I'm still not using a scripting language is because, in theory, this file can still be read line by line ( like many GNU utility do ) and be interpreted correctly .

Comment: OM what way do you want to "know" the tags/values and so forth.  Do you want them in shell variables, printed in some format etc?  What would "success" look like here.  And as I noted, you could probably make `awk` do this, or you could even do it in the shell directly with a `while` loop.

Comment: @EricRenouf I have added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution, assuming you don't want the blank lines in your example output.

```
awk '/START_BLOCK_1/ { block1=$2; next; } \
/END_BLOCK_1/ {block1=""; next; } \
/START_BLOCK_2/ { block2=$2; next; } \
/./ { if(block1) {print block2 " " block1} if(block2) { print block2 " " $2}
}' inp
```

it works by matching each line for a start or end block.  If we are "in" a BLOCK_1 we'll have the name set in the `block1` variable.  If we're "in" a BLOCK_2 we'll have that name set in the `block2` variable.  Any line that doesn't define a block and isn't empty (matches at least 1 character) we'll then print out stuff based on the blocks we're in.

Comment: I think that I still have to tweak it a bit, just because sometimes type 2 blocks can be marked by different tokens but I think we are more or less there . One question : what is the technical or specific name for the `/./` portion and similar ?

Comment: @user31223 the / symbols denote that what is between them is a regular expression.  As a regex `.` matches any single character

Comment: What I meant was the technical name for it, I noticed that `awk` is calling them *patterns* which I think is the name for the *thing*

Comment: @user31223 if you look at the [POSIX definition for `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) you'll see that the general form for the `awk` program is `pattern { action }` and the section on `patterns` shows that regular expressions are one form of accepted patterns, but there are others like the special `BEGIN` and `END` patterns, or other types of expression (like, say, `$1 == "first"`) or a range